# Converting MSAccess Queries to SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I've been trying to modify and input the following the query from an Access database into a SQL Server database but keep getting errors, e.g. "int is not a recognised built in function name".

Any way around this?

```
    SELECT Tasks.Task_id, 
          Days_1.next_working_day AS Day_date

    FROM Intervals 
INNER JOIN ((Days INNER JOIN Days AS Days_1 ON Days.day_of_week = Days_1.day_of_week) 
INNER JOIN Tasks ON Days.Day_date = Tasks.Start_date) 
ON Intervals.Interval_id = Tasks.Interval_id


WHERE (((Days_1.next_working_day)>=[tasks].[start_date])
 AND 
((Intervals.Interval_Type_Name)="Fortnightly") 
AND 
((DateDiff("d",[tasks].[start_date],[days_1].[day_date])/14-int(DateDiff("d",[tasks].[start_date],[days_1].[day_date])/14)<>0)=0))
ORDER BY Days_1.next_working_day;
```

Thanks!

Comment: A lofty goal, but it is really hard to follow the logic in the `where` clause.  The simple answer is that you can do `cast(expression as int)` instead of `int`.  I can't quite figure out what these two comparisons are dong:  <>0)=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is in your `WHERE` clause:

```
... -int(DateDiff("d",[tasks].[start_date],[days_1].[day_date])/14)
```

...which is not valid out of the box (no such built-in function exists). Presumably you're trying to do some rounding with a cast. See [`CAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for T-SQL. You might also want to look into functions [`CEILING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx) and [`FLOOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx). I would be remiss if I didn't suggest revisiting that logic for what you're trying to do.

Regarding the query itself, I gave your `WHERE` clause a second look. As Gordon Linoff points out, what `<>0)=0)` is there for is unclear and is going to be the next error you run into. It looks like maybe the original query intended on extracting 2 week intervals in their entirety in a roundabout way. If so, then my best guess as to what that part of the clause should look like is:

```
(
    DateDiff("d", [tasks].[start_date], [days_1].[day_date]) / 14.0 -
    DateDiff("d", [tasks].[start_date], [days_1].[day_date]) / 14 
    = 0
)
```

Note now the division by 14.0 and not on the 2nd calculation which will always return an `int` because of integer division (so that cast becomes unnecessary).

Better yet, use [modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx):

```
(
    DateDiff("d", [tasks].[start_date], [days_1].[daydate]) % 14 = 0
)
```

I really am not sure if this is what you're going after but it's my best guess without more information.

Comment: I didn't write the original Access query so I'm struggling. What would you suggest I change or where should I put CAST, etc? Thanks

Comment: Check out Gordon Linoff's comment but you can do the equivalent with `cast(DateDiff("d",[tasks].[start_date],[days_1].[day_date])/14 as int)`.

Comment: Thanks, that deals with the int issue, no idea how to deal with ")<>0)=0))" though. It runs if I remove "<>0)" and just leave it as "...AS INT)=0)" but it returns the wrong data.

Comment: I added some comments to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a million! That was really starting to get on my nerves.